# Meaning of fall for a lie

Tags: lyrics

I know *fall for something* means to be tricked (believe someone), but here in lyrics she's adding "like you". Does it mean that she lied to him too? I have doubts about my comprehending, so I need your help.

> Do I wanna be told the truth?
>   When I fell for a lie like you

Comment: What song is it?

Comment: Fell in love with a liar, is what I think it means. We don't know for sure, because it's song lyrics.

Comment: @NVZ I would say the person is a lie not a liar - maybe the image they present is not who they actually are. The woman "fell for them" in the romantic sense and they turned out not to be who she thought they were, so "fell for" is used in two senses.  It's hard to say without proper context.

Comment: @ColleenV Yeah, correct. That's what I had in mind. This must be the context: https://genius.com/Black-honey-dig-lyrics

Comment: @ColleenV, NVZ guys, I think you're right in 100%! thank you